# How to get the IP Address for your Local Area Connection on Windows Server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, ip, scripting, wmi

I want to create a batch or vbs file that will put together a url and executed.  Part of that url needs to be the actual ip address of the machine.  How I am able to get that IP address in a variable to include it on the script?

EDIT 1:

I found out that the command below will give me the IP Address, but still don't know how to get that value into a variable to use it in a script.

```
c:\> wmic NICCONFIG WHERE IPEnabled=true GET IPAddress /format:csv

Node,IPAddress
IP-0AFB,{10.25.5.2}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's some sample code I used in a previous script...

```
Dim myIPAddress : myIPAddress = ""
Dim objWMIService : Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Dim colAdapters : Set colAdapters = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select IPAddress from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Where IPEnabled = True")
Dim objAdapter
For Each objAdapter in colAdapters
  If Not IsNull(objAdapter.IPAddress) Then myIPAddress = trim(objAdapter.IPAddress(0))
  exit for
Next

Wscript.echo "My IPAddress is " & myIPAddress
```

Comment: Thanks! I am getting runtime error: Object Required 'idLocalIPAddress'. Then I added a line Dim idLocalIPAddress, and now I am getting runtime error: Object required: ''. Any comments?

Comment: With Option Explict set you will need to ensure a Dim for every variable...  for my example I just gave you the quick and dirty, leaving it up to you to add the Dim statements...  To step through vbscript you can launch the script with WSCRIPT.EXE //X scriptname.vbs and it will launch the Just-In-Time debugger, allowing you to step through your code in Visual Studio.  Hopefully stepping through your code you can pinpoint the cause of your failure.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return the IP address into a variable, you could do the following:

```
Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = &h10
Const wbemFlagForwardOnly = &h20
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled='TRUE'", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)
For Each objItem In colItems
            strIPAddress = Join(objItem.IPAddress, ",")
            *yourFunctionName*(strIPAddress)
Next
```

This code is taken straight from the Scriptomatic v2.0 from Microsoft's TechNet Scriptcenter.  Found here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd939957.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to extract the WMIC results into a variable in a cmd script:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set varcounter=0
set wmicmd="wmic NICCONFIG WHERE IPEnabled=true GET IPAddress"
for /f "tokens=1 delims={, skip=1" %%a in ('%wmicmd%') do call :SETVAR %%a
endlocal
goto :eof

:SETVAR
set /a varcounter=%varcounter% + 1
if not {%1}=={} (
    echo NIC %varcounter% address is {%1}
    set NIC%varcounter%=%1
)
goto :eof
```

Notice that since there may be multiple NICs, we have to loop through WMIC's output, which is accomplished by calling :SETVAR for each line of WMIC output (skipping the first one, though, and testing for any blank trailing lines. A variable is created for each enabled NIC found - the variables will be %NIC1%, %NIC2%, etc.

Line 12, starting with *"echo NIC"*, can be removed once you have it working to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 1):

You know, to make this REALLLLLY useful, I added `/node:%1` (to get IP of remote computer)
Saves some legwork for system admins & network admins vs. ping or nslookup.
I'm sure the other thing I will add is 'error-checking' so that, IF the system happens to not be available, the script can "log that info" - like `System %1 not available` - and then move on to grab the ip of the next system.

Often, I make a 'bat' to 'call a bat'
So, I would just create a batch file maybe like "getall.bat" below:

Then just run it like this: `getall > getall-log.txt 2>&1`

(Above will pipe out all the info to a text file, including any errors encountered)

getall.bat

```
rem getall.bat
call getnic.bat workstation1
call getnic.bat workstation2
call getnic.bat server1
call getnic.bat server2
rem end of getall.bat
```

getnic.bat

```
rem - getnic.bat
@echo off
setlocal
set varcounter=0
set wmicmd="wmic /node:%1 NICCONFIG WHERE IPEnabled=true GET IPAddress"
for /f "tokens=1 delims={, skip=1" %%a in ('%wmicmd%') do call :SETVAR %%a
endlocal
goto :eof

:SETVAR
set /a varcounter=%varcounter% + 1
if not {%1}=={} (
    echo NIC %varcounter% address is {%1}
    set NIC%varcounter%=%1
)
goto :eof
rem end of getnic.bat
```

Comment: Thanks 'jscott' for editing it. I was in the midst of editing it at same time as you. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Converted for IPv6

```
@echo off
setlocal
set varcounter=0
set wmicmd="wmic NICCONFIG WHERE IPEnabled=true GET IPAddress"
for /f "tokens=2 delims={, skip=1" %%a in ('%wmicmd%') do call :SETVAR %%a
endlocal
goto :eof

:SETVAR
set /a varcounter=%varcounter% + 1
if not {%1}=={} (
    echo NIC %varcounter% IPv6 address is {%1}
    set NIC%varcounter%=%1
)
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for a VBS or Batch style script but I thought I would add a PowerShell snippet as well if you wanted to try that route or for anyone else looking at this question...

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName()) | foreach {write $_.IPAddressToString}
```

This will return all IP Addresses currently assigned to the machine.